# Construct perl command params from the command line

Tags: bash, perl

I would like to add multiple `-e command` dynamically to perl but it throws multiple errors like this:

> String found where operator expected at -e line 2, near
>   "'s/\$testName/\$test-name/g;'"   (Missing semicolon on
>   previous line?)

Heres what I'm doing:

```
find css -name "*.scss" -print0 | \
xargs -0 -t perl -pi \
$(perl -ne '/^(\$(?=[a-z0-9]*[A-Z])[^:\s]+)\s*:/ && print "-e \047s/\\$1/\\" . lc(join("-", split(/(?=[A-Z])/, $1))) . "/g;\047\n"' _variables.scss | sort -ur | tr "\n" " ")
```

The command `$(perl -ne ...)` extracts and transforms some content and outputs something like:

```
-e 's/\$testName/\$test-name/g;' -e 's/\$coolName/\$cool-name/g;' -e 's/\$camelCased/\$camel-cased/g;'
```

As far as I can tell the problem resides in the way bash/perl evaluates the last command, the manual execution of the command output by "xargs -t" works fine.

The following simple case fails too:

```
target="-e 's/\$testName/\$test-name/g;' -e 's/\$coolName/\$cool-name/g;' 's/\$camelCased/\$camel-cased/g;'"
perl -pi $target css/core.scss
```

Comment: Where do you pass the arguments produced by `xargs`, to the outer perl or the inner one?

Comment: To the outer perl: "search and replace all pairs provided by the inner perl".

Comment: You don't get quote removal on the results of variable expansion and command substituion. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ARGS=$(perl -ne '/^(\$(?=[a-z0-9]*[A-Z])[^:\s]+)\s*:/ && print "-e \047s/\\$1/\\" . lc(join("-", split(/(?=[A-Z])/, $1))) . "/g;\047\n"' _variables.scss | sort -ur | tr "\n" " ")
eval "find css -name '*.scss' -print0 | xargs -0 -t perl -pi $ARGS"
```

Or

```
eval "find css -name '*.scss' -print0 | xargs -0 -t perl -pi $(perl -ne '/^(\$(?=[a-z0-9]*[A-Z])[^:\s]+)\s*:/ && print "-e \047s/\\$1/\\" . lc(join("-", split(/(?=[A-Z])/, $1))) . "/g;\047\n"' _variables.scss | sort -ur | tr "\n" " ")"
```

Comment: It works great, is it possible to make it work without the ARGS var? Something similar to @mr-llama suggestion: "find ... | xargs -0 -t eval..."?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include an `eval` with the `xargs` to get the variable to be parsed as parameters.  Here's a quick demonstration:

```
# Variable containing parameters
> target="-e 's/a/b/g;' -e 's/x/y/g;'"

# Variable substitution - Doesn't work
> echo "aaaabbbbccccddddxxxx" | perl -pi ${target}
String found where operator expected at -e line 2, near "'s/x/y/g;'"
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
syntax error at -e line 2, near "'s/x/y/g;'"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

# Manual substitution - Works
> echo "aaaabbbbccccddddxxxx" | perl -pi -e 's/a/b/g;' -e 's/x/y/g;'
bbbbbbbbccccddddyyyy

# Eval substitution - Works
> echo "aaaabbbbccccddddxxxx" | eval perl -pi ${target}
bbbbbbbbccccddddyyyy
```

In your situation, the following should work:

```
find css -name "*.scss" -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -t eval perl -pi $(perl -ne .....)
```

Comment: Thank you @Mr. Llama. I couldn't make it work with eval and xargs. I got this error: "xargs: eval: No such file or directory".

Answer (score 0):

You don't get quote removal on the results of variable expansion and command substituion.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for more details.

You can't get what you want here the way you are trying to do it. Store the results of the inner perl in an array and expand that on the outer perl command.